# Android JobScheduler does not start job when Wi-Fi network appears

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I'm trying to setup `JobScheduler` in order to upload some images to the server over wi-fi.
Here is ho I set it up:

```
    PersistableBundle params = new PersistableBundle();
    params.putString(UploadJobService.EXTRA_MEDIA, GsonFactory.getGson().toJson(mMedia));
    params.putString(UploadJobService.EXTRA_TEMP_ID, tempId);
    params.putInt(UploadJobService.EXTRA_IS_PUBLIC, mIsAlbumPublic.value());

    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, new ComponentName(this, UploadJobService.class));
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED);
    builder.setPersisted(true);
    builder.setExtras(params);
    builder.setOverrideDeadline(DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS);
    JobScheduler.getInstance(this).schedule(builder.build());
```

If wi-fi network is available it uploads my content well. But if I turn it off, force service to be scheduled and then turn wi-fi on it does not start upload.

Am I doing something wrong ? Or `JobScheduler` is not for this purpose and I should use broadcast receiver for network availability ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did find a solution in the meantime, but perhaps this answer helps anyone.

I had the same problem like you and think that in order to reschedule a job you have to specify

```
builder.setBackoffCriteria(long initialBackoffMillis, int backoffPolicy)
```

When I use that, my job which didn't run because of turned-off network, will be rerun after that initialBackoffMillis-period after network is turned on again.
I am not fully happy with that because I would wish for the job to be run immediately after network is turned on again and - in addition - the first time a running of a job is attempted it also uses the initialBackoffMillis delay.
But at least this is a point to start.